# Am I accurate in assuming this about this complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I’m trying to wrap my head around time complexity, am I correct to assume a sort function and nested for loops would assume a time complexity of O(NM) if the sort function is faster than O(N^2)/O(NM) time?

I’m working on a problem where I have an array and sort it with the Python sort() function, which sorts in O(NlogN) time, then I have a nested loop to iterate through two arrays of size N and size M(one of which is the sorted array), Would I be correct in assuming the time complexity is O(N*M) as it could be larger than O(NlogN) in most cases, or am I to include the O(NlogN) complexity in some way?

Comment: O(NlogN + NM) doesn't simplify unless you have some relation between N and M. O(N^2)/O(NM) doesn't mean anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase the situation to make sure I understand it correctly.

You have two arrays A and B, of sizes N and M respectively. You sort A and then iterate over all pairs of elements where one is from A and the other from B.

The sorting does O(N log N) comparisons, assuming you use an appropriate sorting algorithm. The iteration does O(NM) operations (including comparisons between the iterators and the range limits; `i` and `N` and `j` and `M` in typical for loop fashion).

Assuming the operation you do inside the nested loop takes constant time (relative to a comparison), then the total time complexity is the sum of both parts: O(N log N + NM). You can only simplify this if you have a relation between N and M.

If M = O(log N), then O(N log N + NM) = O(N log N).
If log N = O(M), then O(N log N + NM) = O(NM).
Both cases can be true at the same time. That would just mean O(N log N) = O(NM).

Comment: This is a good answer, but comparisons aren't actually constant time even though that's a common assumption when performing complexity calculations.

Comment: @PaulHankin How so? If you mean the time they take can vary, they're still constant time relative to N.

Comment: I mean the amount of time a comparison takes when running on a computer is not constant, which "a comparison takes constant time" implies to me. For example, a string comparison can take arbitrarily long, as can a bigint comparison. You're right the time doesn't depend directly on N, but I don't think that's what's meant by "constant time", and even "constant with respect to N" is dubious and I think confusing if you mean "it varies independently of N".

Comment: I'm nitpicking maybe, but it's fine (and common) to assume that comparisons are constant time to make the analysis possible, and I think this often leads to practical models of runtimes for real data. That doesn't actually mean that comparisons are constant time, since they're not.

Comment: It's true that the comparison time depends on the element type, which is not specified in the question. However, in the context of time complexity, sorting a list of strings is still in O(N log N) comparisons (with a comparison-based algorithm of course). The comparison here is the elementary operation, and is considered to take constant time, precisely because it does not depend on N, the number of elements. I guess "takes constant time (relative to a comparison)" is more accurate.